# Download files on client machine in sharepoint not the server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, network-programming

Please I have a method that create and download file on sharepoint server but i want that these downloads comes to **Client Machine**.

.It'm creating text file programatically and write "Hello World!" in it and want this file path to be on C:\ drive on the Client Machine not the Server.

..Please help me to do That.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to download the file in SharePoint document library.

The download url is `http(s)://yourserver/path/to/your/folder/file.ext`.

> using System.Net;
>
> static class MyClass{
>
> ```
> static WebClient client_ = new WebClient(){
>     Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userid", "password")
> };
>
> public static void Download(string path_in_sp, string path_in_local){
>     client_.DownloadFile(path_in_sp, path_in_local);
> }
> ```
>
> }

When you use Integrated Auth, use `Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` instead.

Comment: I'll explain more to you ..It'm creating text file programatically and write "Hello World!" in it and want this file path to be on C:\ drive on the Client Machine not the Server...Please help me to do That ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say, a text file was generated in SERVER and you want to make it saved in CLIENT machine, right? Is that app a visual web parts or any other kind of web app? Share your code and you could get more advices!

Comment: Dear Panda Drunkard, can u help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659661/download-file-on-the-machine-that-use-sharepoint-site-not-the-machine-that-has-s

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this code

```
var remotefile = @"https://your sharePoint file addess";
var localfile = @"clientmachine address";
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  // or new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass","domain");
  wc.DownloadFile(remotefile,localfile);
```

}

Comment: but the file path is on the server hard drive not in URL ?

Comment: I don't know clientmachine address.  what i have is string path on server hard drive and string path on client hard drive, Waht should i do then?? please help me Thanks.

Comment: Dear Shaym Sunder Shah , your answer is good But WebClient.DownloadFile downloads on the machine that has sharepoint only not the machine that use the site, plz help me to mark ur answer as correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659661/download-file-on-the-machine-that-use-sharepoint-site-not-the-machine-that-has-s

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# expert, but here it is in VB. Shouldn't be too hard to make sense of. My files were all xls, so I hard-coded that as the extension, but you could also use the FileLeafRef property instead of JobName, which is typically the actual filename. In my case the JobName property was more succinct so I wanted my local files to be named using that, thus had to add my own extension.

Long story short, the key is using OpenBinaryDirect then writing it using system.io:

```
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Module Main
    Sub main()
        Dim context As New ClientContext("<<YOUR SHAREPOINT URL>>")
        Dim webcontent As Web = context.Web
        Dim weblist As ListCollection = context.Web.Lists

        context.Load(weblist)
        context.ExecuteQuery()

        Dim testList As List = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("<<YOUR SHAREPOINT LIBRARY>>")
        Dim query As CamlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()
        Dim items As ListItemCollection = testList.GetItems(query)
        context.Load(items)
        context.ExecuteQuery()
        For Each listItem As ListItem In items
            Dim myJobName = listItem.FieldValues("JobName")
            If Not myJobName Is Nothing Then
                Dim myDownload As FileInformation
                Dim myOutFile As String = "C:\test\"
                Dim myModDt = Date.Parse(listItem.FieldValues("Modified").ToString).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
                myDownload = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, listItem("FileRef").ToString)
                myOutFile += myJobName & "_" & myModDt & ".xls"
                Dim fileStream As Object = System.IO.File.Create(myOutFile)
                myDownload.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Hope this helps!