# WebPart on Sharepoint downloads a file locally - I need to send it to the client

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, download, webclient

please help me to Download file on the machine that use  Sharepoint Site not the machine that has sharepoint server.

```
public class WebClientBL
{
    static WebClient client_ = new WebClient()
    {
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
    };

    public static void DownloadToClient(string path_in_sp, string path_in_local)
    {
        try
        {
            client_.DownloadFile(path_in_sp, path_in_local);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we assume this doesn't work in some way? I further assume you see an exception in the `catch` block - please capture the stack trace for this in the debugger, and add it to the end of your question. This will greatly help you get a quick answer.

Comment: Dear   Chris Ballard, It has no exception it download normally on the sharepoint server machine not the client machine that use the sharepoint site , got it? plz help me

Comment: We'd love to help, but in order to do that, you need to go a little further to provide enough information for people to understand your problem. So, for example, where does the code you posted run (is it on the client machine? what is it, a winforms app, console app?) - what do you mean "it downloads normally on the sharepoint server machine"? - you mean it ends up on disk there? What actual paths do you provide for the parameters `path_in_sp` and `path_in_local`?

Comment: Dear  Chris Ballard, It's Sharepoint and my code runs in web part that  that has button that's used to download a text file that I want to download it the Client Machine that uses Sharepoint Site not Sharepoint serevr .any Way I have updated the code .

Comment: Great - that is the missing detail we needed. I will update your question and title, so that others can see.

Comment: ///calling the method as it it.
//string LocalPath = @"C:\TestClient\fileName.txt";
            //    string testPath = "SeverPatente/report1.txt";
            //    WebClientBL.DownloadToClient(testPath, LocalPath);

Comment: Dear Chris Ballard,   Thanks for ur edit but I need help in that urgently now if you can help me in any way i'll be grateful to You.